# append() alternative for jQuery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, frontend

Let's assume that I want the following javascript to appear in my HTML page:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
var presenter = null;

function setup3dhop() { 
    presenter = new Presenter("draw-canvas");

    presenter.setScene({
        meshes: {
            "mesh_1" : { url: "models/gargo.nxz" }
        },
        modelInstances : {
            "instance_1" : { mesh : "mesh_1" } 
        }
    });
}

setup3dhop();

document.getElementById('draw-canvas').setAttribute('width', document.body.clientWidth);
document.getElementById("draw-canvas").setAttribute('height', document.body.clientHeight);
</script>
```

The way I insert the above piece of code into my HTML page is via a jQuery function. Specifically, I do this:

```
$(useTab).append('<script> \n' +                                                                                         
    'var presenter = null; \n \n' +                                                                                            
                                                                                                                               
    'function setup3dhop() { \n' +                                                                                             
         'presenter = new Presenter("draw-canvas");  \n' +                                                                     
                                                                                                                               
          'presenter.setScene({ \n' +                                                                                          
                                                                                                                               
                  'meshes: { \n' +                                                                            
                          "\"mesh_1\" : { url: " + "\"" + referenceUrl + "\"" + ", \n" +                      
                          "mType     : \"ply\"} \n" +                                                         
                  '}, \n' +                                                                                   
                  'modelInstances : { \n' +                                                                   
                          '"instance_1" : { mesh : "mesh_1" } \n' +                                    
                  '} \n' +                                                                             
          '}); \n' +                                                                                     
    '}; \n' +                                                                                            
                                                                                                         
    'init3dhop(); \n' +                                                                                  
                                                                                                         
    'setup3dhop(); \n' +                                                                                 
                                                                                                         
    'resizeCanvas(640,480); \n' +                                                                        
                                                                                                         
    'document.getElementById(\'draw-canvas\').setAttribute(\'width\', document.body.clientWidth); \n' +  
    'document.getElementById(\'draw-canvas\').setAttribute(\'height\', document.body.clientHeight); \n' +
    '</script>'                                                                                          
    );
```

Is there a better way to do the same thing? Because using append things get really complicated really fast. Thank you!

Comment: Why not just paste the code into the website by itself?

Comment: You can save the code into a text file and then read it and append to your desired html element.

Comment: How can I read in a text file into JavaScript? I'm sorry but I'm new to JavaScript.

Comment: Sorry, I mean jQuery. How can I have my code into a text file, read in into jQuery, and append it as a js script?